# Get rid of duplicate character that are not necessarily adjacent

Tags: java, arrays, string, loops

So I was asked to have two different arrays that both stored 5 random numbers and if any number between each array were the same, they would be printed out.

```
// Creates Arrays   
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            first5num[i] = rand.nextInt(9 + 1);
            System.out.print(" " + first5num[i]);
        }

        for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
        {
            second5num[j] = rand.nextInt(9 + 1);
            System.out.print(" " + second5num[j]);
        }

//Loops through arrays to find duplicates
        for (int k = 0; k < 5; k++)
        {
            comparitive = first5num[k];
            for (int l = 0; l < 5; l++)
            {
                if (comparitive == second5num[l])
                {
                    SameNums += comparitive;
                }
            }
        }
```

I was able to get it working and it would print out the shared numbers between both arrays. I stored the Shared numbers into a string called SameNums and now I must ensure that the string does not hold any duplicate numbers. For example Array1 = 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 and Array2 = 1, 2, 3, 5, 5. The  SameNums string would hold "12355". How do I ensure that 5 is only listed once and please keep in mind that the string may include duplicates that are not directly next to each other (12928 should get rid of the second 2. Below is my train of thought so far:

```
//Manipulates string using while loop
            while (run == true)
            {
            if (counter == SameNums.length() - 1)
            {
                run = false;
            }
            if (SameNums.charAt(counter) == SameNums.charAt(restrict))
            {
                word1 = SameNums.substring(0, restrict);
                word3 = SameNums.substring(restrict + 1, SameNums.length());
                SameNums = word1 + word3;
                counter++;
                restrict = counter + 1;
                continue;
            }
```

How can I make the string read no duplicate chars?*

Comment: The simplest way is to keep a `Set<Integer>`.

Answer (score 0):

```
//add random integers into a common array list, than filter that list "duplicates" for duplicates.

    Random rand = new Random();
    ArrayList<Integer> duplicates = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<Integer> first5num = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<Integer> second5num = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        first5num.add(i, rand.nextInt(10));
        duplicates.add(i, first5num.get(i));

    }

    for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
        second5num.add(j, rand.nextInt(10));
        duplicates.add(j, second5num.get(j));

    }

    Map<Integer, Long> frequencies = duplicates.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), Collectors.counting()));
    frequencies.entrySet().stream()
            .filter(entry -> entry.getValue() > 1)
            .forEach(entry -> System.out.println(entry.getKey()));
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Simply use Set and set.retainAll() to find the intersection. See snippet code below:

```
        Integer[] first5num = {1,2,3,4,5};
        Integer[] second5num = {2,3,3,5,6};

        Set<Integer> set1 = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(first5num));
        Set<Integer> set2 = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(second5num));

        set1.retainAll(set2);
        // now set1 only contains the intersection between the 2 sets
        System.out.println(set1);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    //this prints out the duplicate values, and a final array with no duplicates
            Random rand = new Random();
            ArrayList<Integer> duplicates = new ArrayList<>();
            ArrayList<Integer> finalArray = new ArrayList<>();
            ArrayList<Integer> first5num = new ArrayList<>();
            ArrayList<Integer> second5num = new ArrayList<>();
            first5num.add(4);
            first5num.add(7);
            first5num.add(0);
            first5num.add(10);
            first5num.add(4);
    
            second5num.add(4);
            second5num.add(6);
            second5num.add(5);
            second5num.add(0);
            second5num.add(4);
            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
                duplicates.add(i, first5num.get(i));
            }
            for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
                duplicates.add(j, second5num.get(j));
            }
    
            Map<Integer, Long> frequencies = duplicates.stream()
                    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), Collectors.counting()));
    
            frequencies.entrySet().stream()
                    .filter(entry -> entry.getValue() > 1)
                    .forEach(entry -> System.out.println(entry.getKey()));
// prints an array with no duplicates    
            frequencies.entrySet().stream()
                    .filter(entry -> entry.getValue() ==1)
                    .forEach(entry ->finalArray.add(entry.getKey()));
            System.out.println(finalArray);
```

Comment: Output 0
4
[5, 6, 7, 10]

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).